# Add a bitmap to the ground of a Google SketchUp model?

Tags: 3d-modeling, sketchup, modeling

Is it possible to add a bitmap to the floor ground of a [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) model?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Just make a a ground plane first, and then apply the texture as you would any other plane.  You will have to then hide that plane as you continue to work on the model, as otherwise it would stop you from seeing everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the paint bucket tool.

Here is the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvSP54o_KqY).

Windows:
In the Materials selection window, click the edit tab, under Texture is a file selection field.

Mac:
In the Colors selection window, click the brick icon, then do a contextual click (right click) in the texture choices to bring up the "New Texture..." menu which will ask you for your file.